# How do I extract primary constructor params with a quasiquote

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes, scala-macro-paradise

I'm currently using:

```
annottees map (_.tree) match {
  case (classDef @ q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }")
  :: Nil =>
```

to extract both the `classDef` and the `paramss`. Is there anyway that this could be less verbose? Perhaps something that extracts `paramss` from pattern matching a `classDef: ClassDef`?